# Can RFM98PW 3V3 Regulator Cause Heating

Tags: rf, heat, 3.3v

I'm using RFM98PW RF module that is supplied by 5 volts. This module has SX1278 on board which is supplied by 3V3. So there is a 3V3 regulator on board. As you can see in the diagram below there is a 3V3 out pin (pin 9) on the module. [image]

I don't connect the 3V3 pin (pin 9) anywhere on my circuit board and I wondered whether or  not this would cause the module to heat up. My module heats up a lot so I thought this could be the cause of my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you suspect regulator instability, putting less load on a regulator generally leads to less heating.

Comment: What else do you have connected?  Do you have a 5V microcontroller connected?  That would be bad because the RFM98PW expects a maximum of 3.3V on its digital pins.

Comment: Is it cool in Rx mode? If not oh oh

Answer (score 2):

The [datasheet](https://www.hoperf.com/data/upload/portal/20190301/RFM98PW.pdf) says:

On page 3:

> Voltage on Digital Control Inputs -0.3 3.3 + 0.3 V 
> Voltage on AnalogInputs -0.3 3.3 + 0.3 V

From these, we can assume the major current is drawn to 3.3V.

On page 4:

> TX Working current 700mA

Total wattage = 5V * 700mA = 3.5W.
The wattage lose on LDO = (5V - 3V) * 700mA = 1.4W.

For that geometry (?) of the device, I would expect some heat on my finger when touched.

BTW, I could not find the "power consumption" on the datasheet. It is not nice, if that is missing at all.